# How to compare multiple ArrayList

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I am new to java programming. Could you please help me the programming logic for below scenario.

Compare each array value till its find un-matching id

ex:

A1 : [ID_2, ID_0]

A2 : [ID_4, ID_2]

A3 : [ID_6, ID_4]

A4 : [ID_8, ID_6]

A5 : [ID_10, ID_8]

A6 : [ID_12, ID_10]

A7 : [ID_14, ID_12]

A8 : [ID_16, ID_14]

A9 : [ID_18, ID_16]

A10: [ID_20, ID_18]

A11: [ID_25, ID_18]

compare A1--->ID_2 with A2-->ID_2

if same then compare A2-->ID_4 with A3-->ID_4 and so on

When there will be any unmatched id found then stop the comparison.

Comment: you loop through the arrays comparing each value to the current index of the first array

Comment: Could you please help me on sample logic

Comment: im not going to write it for you because i haven't seen you try anything. But at a high level create a method or a function that takes an array and target value as parameters. have this method loop through the array checking each index for that target value. If it finds it return true or whatever. Have another function or method which has access to the first array and the rest of them. In a loop of the first array call the previous function with the target value and what ever array you want to search if the function returns true stop if false continue. This is a crude way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for these information.I will write as per above explained.